# From terminal, can't access folders on my external hard drive, connected to my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (laptop). my external hard drive is already mounted

Tags: command-line, mount, external-hdd

From Ubuntu terminal, can't access folders on my external hard drive, which is connected to my  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (laptop). my external hard drive is already mounted.

Comment: Run this: `mount` but only post above in question the one line that is your mount. If automounted it will be something like /media/$USER/xxxx where user is your id on system and xxx is label you have for that partition.  You do have partition(s) not just drive? And better to label partitions, so mounted by label which you can understand, instead of some long UUID. If NTFS make sure you do not have Windows fast start up on which sets hibernation flag, preventing read/write from Linux.

Comment: Thanks I got it.